# Unable to launch Cucumber tests with Idea

Tags: java, testing, gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber

Unable to launch cucumber tests with Idea. Please, help.

My environment:

> Idea 2018.2 with all latest update; Gradle 3.5; JDK 1.8.0_172; Latest
>   cucumber plugin;

Dependencies

```
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '5.0.2'
    compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-junit4', version: '2.6.0'
    compile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.9.1'

    testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '3.0.2'
    testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '3.0.2'
```

Structure:

```
main -> baseclass -> BaseClass (core of my Appium/Selenium project)
test -> cucumbersteps: 
          - MyStepDefs
          - RunnerTest
test -> resources -> cucumbersteps -> open_day.feature
```

When i launching RunnerTest with command:

```
gradlew clean test --tests ru.cucumbersteps.RunnerTest
```

**my tests is passing** but when i trying to run tests with Idea configuration my tests **failing** with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException


Failed scenarios:
1 Scenarios (1 failed)
6 Steps (1 failed, 3 skipped, 2 passed)
0m1,001s
```

I'm creating run configuration with Idea:

```
Main class: cucumber.api.cli.Main
Glue: ru.cucumbersteps
Feature: C:/git/JunitPOM/src/test/resources/cucumbersteps/01.open_day.feature
Arguments: --name "^Open day$"
Classpath: JunitPOM_test
```

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project to reproduce attached.

Comment: Does it work with Idea 2018.1?